# Performance of Pandas apply vs np.vectorize to create new column from existing columns

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, performance, numpy

I am using Pandas dataframes and want to create a new column as a function of existing columns. I have not seen a good discussion of the speed difference between `df.apply()` and `np.vectorize()`, so I thought I would ask here.

The Pandas `apply()` function is slow. From what I measured (shown below in some experiments), using `np.vectorize()` is 25x faster (or more) than using the DataFrame function `apply()` , at least on my 2016 MacBook Pro. **Is this an expected result, and why?**

For example, suppose I have the following dataframe with `N` rows:

```
N = 10
A_list = np.random.randint(1, 100, N)
B_list = np.random.randint(1, 100, N)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': A_list, 'B': B_list})
df.head()
#     A   B
# 0  78  50
# 1  23  91
# 2  55  62
# 3  82  64
# 4  99  80
```

Suppose further that I want to create a new column as a function of the two columns `A` and `B`. In the example below, I'll use a simple function `divide()`. To apply the function, I can use either `df.apply()` or `np.vectorize()`:

```
def divide(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        return 0.0
    return float(a)/b

df['result'] = df.apply(lambda row: divide(row['A'], row['B']), axis=1)

df['result2'] = np.vectorize(divide)(df['A'], df['B'])

df.head()
#     A   B    result   result2
# 0  78  50  1.560000  1.560000
# 1  23  91  0.252747  0.252747
# 2  55  62  0.887097  0.887097
# 3  82  64  1.281250  1.281250
# 4  99  80  1.237500  1.237500
```

If I increase `N` to real-world sizes like 1 million or more, then I observe that `np.vectorize()` is 25x faster or more than `df.apply()`.

Below is some complete benchmarking code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

def divide(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        return 0.0
    return float(a)/b

for N in [1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000]:    

    print ''
    A_list = np.random.randint(1, 100, N)
    B_list = np.random.randint(1, 100, N)
    df = pd.DataFrame({'A': A_list, 'B': B_list})

    start_epoch_sec = int(time.time())
    df['result'] = df.apply(lambda row: divide(row['A'], row['B']), axis=1)
    end_epoch_sec = int(time.time())
    result_apply = end_epoch_sec - start_epoch_sec

    start_epoch_sec = int(time.time())
    df['result2'] = np.vectorize(divide)(df['A'], df['B'])
    end_epoch_sec = int(time.time())
    result_vectorize = end_epoch_sec - start_epoch_sec


    print 'N=%d, df.apply: %d sec, np.vectorize: %d sec' % \
            (N, result_apply, result_vectorize)

    # Make sure results from df.apply and np.vectorize match.
    assert(df['result'].equals(df['result2']))
```

The results are shown below:

```
N=1000, df.apply: 0 sec, np.vectorize: 0 sec

N=10000, df.apply: 1 sec, np.vectorize: 0 sec

N=100000, df.apply: 2 sec, np.vectorize: 0 sec

N=1000000, df.apply: 24 sec, np.vectorize: 1 sec

N=10000000, df.apply: 262 sec, np.vectorize: 4 sec
```

If `np.vectorize()` is in general always faster than `df.apply()`, then why is `np.vectorize()` not mentioned more? I only ever see StackOverflow posts related to `df.apply()`, such as:

[pandas create new column based on values from other columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886653/pandas-create-new-column-based-on-values-from-other-columns)

[How do I use Pandas 'apply' function to multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16353729/how-do-i-use-pandas-apply-function-to-multiple-columns)

[How to apply a function to two columns of Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331698/how-to-apply-a-function-to-two-columns-of-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: I didnt dig into the details of you question but `np.vectorize` is basically a python `for` loop (it's a convenience method) and `apply` with a lambda is also in python time

Comment: "If np.vectorize() is in general always faster than df.apply(), then why is np.vectorize() not mentioned more?" Because you shouldn't be using `apply` on a row-by-row basis unless you have to, and obviously a vectorized function will out-perform a non-vectorized one.

Comment: @PMende but `np.vectorize` is not vectorized. It's a well-known misnomer

Comment: @roganjosh is correct.  `np.vectorize` simply provides the abiluty to apply a function to an entire array, rather than to each element, it does not avoid iteration.  From the docs: "The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop."

Comment: @roganjosh It's definitely **not** "basically a python `for` loop", either. For example: `%timeit for _, row in df.iterrows(): foo(*row)` results in `7.62 s ± 165 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`. `%timeit foo_v(df['A'], df['B'])` results in `15.4 ms ± 353 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)`. Here, `foo_v = np.vectorize(foo)` and foo is simply defined as: `return float('nan') if b == 0 else a/b`.

Comment: @PMende, Just because the timings are orders of magnitude different does **not** mean they aren't both Python level loops. There are overheads with dataframes that don't exist with NumPy arrays.

Comment: @PMende I have no idea what you're illustrating there. `iterrows` is not a python method. What you should be more concerned about is what the library does under the covers

Comment: @jpp You can do the same thing on the actual numpy arrays if you want. E.g., `A_arr, B_arr = df['A'].values, df['B'].values` then calling `%timeit for a, b in zip(A_arr, B_arr): foo(a, b)` reduces the timings to: `1.88 s ± 57 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`. There is more going on than just "python loops".

Comment: @PMende, Sure, I didn't imply otherwise. You shouldn't derive your opinions on implementation from timings. Yes, they're insightful. But they can make you presume things that aren't true.

Comment: @jpp I was responding to the comment that `np.vectorize` was basically a **python** `for` loop. This isn't the case. You can definitely tell it's not vectorized by comparing to a truly vectorized function. Usually you can do everything you'd want using built-in `numpy` functionality.

Comment: @PMende have a play with pandas `.str` accessors. They're slower than list comprehensions in a lot of cases. We assume too much.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 The answer to your question is probably also dependent on how complex the function is that you want to apply. Will your function always be a 'straight-forward' numerical operation like the `divide` example that you've given here, or can your function also be much longer and more complex?

Comment: @Xukrao: Sometimes the functions are complex (e.g. processing a list of strings from a column), but usually they are short.

Answer (score 248, accepted):

I will *start* by saying that the power of Pandas and NumPy arrays is derived from high-performance **vectorised** calculations on numeric arrays.<sup>1</sup> The entire point of vectorised calculations is to avoid Python-level loops by moving calculations to highly optimised C code and utilising contiguous memory blocks.<sup>2</sup>

#### Python-level loops

Now we can look at some timings. Below are **all** Python-level loops which produce either `pd.Series`, `np.ndarray` or `list` objects containing the same values. For the purposes of assignment to a series within a dataframe, the results are comparable.

```
# Python 3.6.5, NumPy 1.14.3, Pandas 0.23.0

np.random.seed(0)
N = 10**5

%timeit list(map(divide, df['A'], df['B']))                                   # 43.9 ms
%timeit np.vectorize(divide)(df['A'], df['B'])                                # 48.1 ms
%timeit [divide(a, b) for a, b in zip(df['A'], df['B'])]                      # 49.4 ms
%timeit [divide(a, b) for a, b in df[['A', 'B']].itertuples(index=False)]     # 112 ms
%timeit df.apply(lambda row: divide(*row), axis=1, raw=True)                  # 760 ms
%timeit df.apply(lambda row: divide(row['A'], row['B']), axis=1)              # 4.83 s
%timeit [divide(row['A'], row['B']) for _, row in df[['A', 'B']].iterrows()]  # 11.6 s
```

Some takeaways:

1. The `tuple`-based methods (the first 4) are a factor more efficient than `pd.Series`-based methods (the last 3).
2. `np.vectorize`, list comprehension + `zip` and `map` methods, i.e. the top 3, all have roughly the same performance. This is because they use `tuple` *and* bypass some Pandas overhead from `pd.DataFrame.itertuples`.
3. There is a significant speed improvement from using `raw=True` with `pd.DataFrame.apply` versus without. This option feeds NumPy arrays to the custom function instead of `pd.Series` objects.

#### `pd.DataFrame.apply`: just another loop

To see *exactly* the objects Pandas passes around, you can amend your function trivially:

```
def foo(row):
    print(type(row))
    assert False  # because you only need to see this once
df.apply(lambda row: foo(row), axis=1)
```

Output: `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`. Creating, passing and querying a Pandas series object carries significant overheads relative to NumPy arrays. This shouldn't be surprise: Pandas series include a decent amount of scaffolding to hold an index, values, attributes, etc.

Do the same exercise again with `raw=True` and you'll see `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`. All this is described in the docs, but seeing it is more convincing.

#### `np.vectorize`: fake vectorisation

The docs for [`np.vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html#numpy.vectorize) has the following note:

> The vectorized function evaluates `pyfunc` over successive tuples of
>   the input arrays like the python map function, except it uses the
>   broadcasting rules of numpy.

The "broadcasting rules" are irrelevant here, since the input arrays have the same dimensions. The parallel to `map` is instructive, since the `map` version above has almost identical performance. The [source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.15.1/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L1760-L2118) shows what's happening: `np.vectorize` converts your input function into a [Universal function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/ufuncs.html) ("ufunc") via [`np.frompyfunc`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.frompyfunc.html#numpy.frompyfunc). There is some optimisation, e.g. caching, which can lead to some performance improvement.

In short, `np.vectorize` does what a Python-level loop *should* do, but `pd.DataFrame.apply` adds a chunky overhead. There's no JIT-compilation which you see with [`numba`](http://numba.pydata.org/) (see below). It's [just a convenience](https://www.mail-archive.com/numpy-discussion@scipy.org/msg00587.html).

#### True vectorisation: what you *should* use

Why aren't the above differences mentioned anywhere? Because the performance of truly vectorised calculations make them irrelevant:

```
%timeit np.where(df['B'] == 0, 0, df['A'] / df['B'])       # 1.17 ms
%timeit (df['A'] / df['B']).replace([np.inf, -np.inf], 0)  # 1.96 ms
```

Yes, that's ~40x faster than the fastest of the above loopy solutions. Either of these are acceptable. In my opinion, the first is succinct, readable and efficient. Only look at other methods, e.g. `numba` below, if performance is critical and this is part of your bottleneck.

#### `numba.njit`: greater efficiency

When loops *are* considered viable they are usually optimised via `numba` with underlying NumPy arrays to move as much as possible to C.

Indeed, `numba` improves performance to *microseconds*. Without some cumbersome work, it will be difficult to get much more efficient than this.

```
from numba import njit

@njit
def divide(a, b):
    res = np.empty(a.shape)
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if b[i] != 0:
            res[i] = a[i] / b[i]
        else:
            res[i] = 0
    return res

%timeit divide(df['A'].values, df['B'].values)  # 717 µs
```

Using `@njit(parallel=True)` may provide a further boost for larger arrays.

---

<sup>1</sup> Numeric types include: `int`, `float`, `datetime`, `bool`, `category`. They *exclude* `object` dtype and can be held in contiguous memory blocks.

<sup>2</sup> 
There are at least 2 reasons why NumPy operations are efficient versus Python:

- Everything in Python is an object. This includes, unlike C, numbers. Python types therefore have an overhead which does not exist with native C types.
- NumPy methods are usually C-based. In addition, optimised algorithms
  are used where possible.

Comment: As a comment on "Creating, passing and querying a Pandas series object carries significant overheads relative to NumPy arrays." Compare: `%timeit [divide(a, b) for a, b in zip(df['A'], df['B'])]` results in: `16.4 ms ± 192 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)` versus: `%timeit [divide(a, b) for a, b in zip(df['A'].values, df['B'].values)]` results in `34.8 ms ± 388 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`. This difference is consistent even if you pull the access of the `.values` attribute out of the loop.

Comment: @PMende, You missed the point here, the series created with `apply` are **row-wise**, i.e. one element from `A` and one from `B` for *each* series. With the list comprehensions, `df['A']` / `df['B']` are the *only* 2 series and they aren't "created" in any sense, they already exist. `zip` can be compared to producing a `tuple`, which is much cheaper.

Comment: @Bazingaa, For `N = 10**5`, I actually found it faster *without* `parallel=True`, but this may work for larger arrays, e.g. I see ~10% improvement for `N = 10**6`.

Comment: Yes, I tried for `10**8` and `10**9` and found it faster

Comment: You have a double check for b[i] != 0. Normal Python and Numba behaviour is to check for 0 and to throw an error. This likely breaks any SIMD vectorization and have usually a high influence on execution speed. But you can change that within Numba to @njit(error_model='numpy') to avoid this double checking for a division by 0. It is also recommendable to allocate memory with np.empty and set the result to 0 within an else statement.

Comment: @max9111, Thanks for the tip re: error_model. If we used this approach would you suggest `res[res == np.inf] = 0` as a separate step? It seems you can't default "DivisionByZero" to give 0.

Comment: error_model numpy uses what the processor gives in a division by 0 -> NaN. At least in Numba 0.41dev both versions uses SIMD-vectorization. You can check this as described here https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/faq.html (1.16.2.3. Why my loop is not vectorized?) I would simply add an else statement to your function (res[i]=0.) and allcocate memory with np.empty. This should combined with the error_model='numpy' improve performance by about 20%. On older Numba versions there was a higher influence on performance...

Comment: @jpp: Thank you for the authoritative answer. Can you please add to your post with a summary of best practices, like when to use `apply()`, `np.vectorize()`, and `numba`? Should we always use `numba` since your measurements show it's the fastest?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010, I've added a note. In my opinion, the `np.where` solution is the one you should go for, and `numba` if you need better performance.

Comment: @jpp: Thanks for the follow-up. Your recommendation to use `np.where(df['B'] == 0, 0, df['A'] / df['B'])` is very specific to my `divide()` function's code that I used as an example. I'm actually interested in arbitrary functions that take columns as input and generate a new column. Do you think `np.where` is applicable in general?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010, There's no universal answer "for arbitrary functions". You have to choose the right tool for the right job, which is part of understanding programming / algorithms.

Comment: @jpp: I'm not sure why you don't understand my question. I want to apply an arbitrary function that takes columns as input and generates a new column. I want the right tool that can perform that task. I'm pretty sure that I understand programming and algorithms. For some reason you are obsessed with my original `divide()` function and only know about `np.where()`. I'm not going to write `divide()` functions for every job.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010, I understand your question. I'm telling you there's no one *recommended* answer for all functions. An arbitrary function may or may not be vectorisable. If it's vectorisable, you should vectorise it. If it's not, then you can use `pd.DataFrame.apply` / `pd.Series.map` / list comprehension / `list` + `map`.

Answer (score 12):

The more complex your functions get (i.e., the less `numpy` can move to its own internals), the more you will see that the performance won't be that different. For example:

```
name_series = pd.Series(np.random.choice(['adam', 'chang', 'eliza', 'odom'], replace=True, size=100000))

def parse_name(name):
    if name.lower().startswith('a'):
        return 'A'
    elif name.lower().startswith('e'):
        return 'E'
    elif name.lower().startswith('i'):
        return 'I'
    elif name.lower().startswith('o'):
        return 'O'
    elif name.lower().startswith('u'):
        return 'U'
    return name

parse_name_vec = np.vectorize(parse_name)
```

Doing some timings:

**Using Apply**

```
%timeit name_series.apply(parse_name)
```

Results:

```
76.2 ms ± 626 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

**Using `np.vectorize`**

```
%timeit parse_name_vec(name_series)
```

Results:

```
77.3 ms ± 216 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Numpy tries to turn python functions into numpy `ufunc` objects when you call `np.vectorize`. How it does this, I don't actually know - you'd have to dig more into the internals of numpy than I'm willing to ATM. That said, it seems to do a better job on simply numerical functions than this string-based function here.

**Cranking the size up to 1,000,000:**

```
name_series = pd.Series(np.random.choice(['adam', 'chang', 'eliza', 'odom'], replace=True, size=1000000))
```

**`apply`**

```
%timeit name_series.apply(parse_name)
```

Results:

```
769 ms ± 5.88 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**`np.vectorize`**

```
%timeit parse_name_vec(name_series)
```

Results:

```
794 ms ± 4.85 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

A better (*vectorized*) way with `np.select`:

```
cases = [
    name_series.str.lower().str.startswith('a'), name_series.str.lower().str.startswith('e'),
    name_series.str.lower().str.startswith('i'), name_series.str.lower().str.startswith('o'),
    name_series.str.lower().str.startswith('u')
]
replacements = 'A E I O U'.split()
```

Timings:

```
%timeit np.select(cases, replacements, default=name_series)
```

Results:

```
67.2 ms ± 683 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure your assertions here are incorrect. I can't back that statement up with code for now, hopefully someone else can