# Pandas - calculate new column with variable column input

Tags: python, pandas

heres the problem... Imagine the following dataframe as an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'col2': [3, 4, 5, 6, 7],'col3': [3, 4, 5, 6, 7],'col4': [1, 2, 3, 3, 2]})
```

Now, I would like to add another column "col 5" which is calculated as follows:

if the value of "col4" is 1, then give me the corresponding value in the column with index 1 (i.e. "col2" in this case), if "col4" is 2 give me the corresponding value in the column with index 2 (i.e. "col3" in this case), etc.

I have tried the below and variations of it, but I can't seem to get the right result

```
df["col5"] = df.apply(lambda x: df.iloc[x,df[df.columns[df["col4"]]]])
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `'col4'` is the indicator of column index, this will work:

```
df['col5'] = df.apply(lambda x: x[df.columns[x['col4']]], axis=1)

df

#   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
#0     1     3     3     1     3
#1     2     4     4     2     4
#2     3     5     5     3     3
#3     4     6     6     3     3
#4     5     7     7     2     7
```

Comment: Indeed, thanks. I actually tried something similar, but without the axis argument...

Comment: Note this solution involves a Python-level loop. You may find a list comprehension better. See [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52673285/performance-of-pandas-apply-vs-np-vectorize-to-create-new-column-from-existing-c/52674448#52674448).

Answer (score 1):

You can use fancy indexing with NumPy and avoid a Python-level loop altogether:

```
df['col5'] = df.iloc[:, :4].values[np.arange(df.shape[0]), df['col4']]

print(df)

   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
0     1     3     3     1     3
1     2     4     4     2     4
2     3     5     5     3     3
3     4     6     6     3     3
4     5     7     7     2     7
```

You should see significant performance benefits for larger dataframes:

```
df = pd.concat([df]*10**4, ignore_index=True)

%timeit df.apply(lambda x: x[df.columns[x['col4']]], axis=1)       # 2.36 s per loop
%timeit df.iloc[:, :4].values[np.arange(df.shape[0]), df['col4']]  # 1.01 ms per loop
```

Comment: Amazing, works. Thank you! One more thing: How would I add a condition to this, i.e. only do this if value in col4 is > 1 e.g. and otherwise take 0?

Comment: @SanMu, No problem, have updated in fact to match what I *think* you need, i.e. `1` maps to `col2`. Feel free to accept a solution that helped.

Comment: @SanMu, you can use `np.where`, e.g. `np.where(df['col4'] > 1, ..., 0)`.