# Get the nearest distance with two geodataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, geolocation, geopandas

Here is my first geodatframe :

```
!pip install geopandas
import pandas as pd
import geopandas

city1 = [{'City':"Buenos Aires","Country":"Argentina","Latitude":-34.58,"Longitude":-58.66},
           {'City':"Brasilia","Country":"Brazil","Latitude":-15.78 ,"Longitude":-70.66},
         {'City':"Santiago","Country":"Chile ","Latitude":-33.45 ,"Longitude":-70.66 }]
city2 =  [{'City':"Bogota","Country":"Colombia ","Latitude":4.60 ,"Longitude":-74.08},
           {'City':"Caracas","Country":"Venezuela","Latitude":10.48  ,"Longitude":-66.86}]
city1df = pd.DataFrame(city1)
city2df = pd.DataFrame(city2)
gcity1df = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(
    city1df, geometry=geopandas.points_from_xy(city1df.Longitude, city1df.Latitude))
gcity2df = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(
    city2df, geometry=geopandas.points_from_xy(city2df.Longitude, city2df.Latitude))
```

City1

```
           City    Country  Latitude  Longitude                     geometry
0  Buenos Aires  Argentina    -34.58     -58.66  POINT (-58.66000 -34.58000)
1      Brasilia     Brazil    -15.78     -47.91  POINT (-47.91000 -15.78000)
2      Santiago      Chile    -33.45     -70.66  POINT (-70.66000 -33.45000)
```

and my second geodataframe :
City2 :

```
         City    Country  Latitude  Longitude                     geometry
1        Bogota   Colombia      4.60     -74.08    POINT (-74.08000 4.60000)
2       Caracas  Venezuela     10.48     -66.86   POINT (-66.86000 10.48000)
```

i would like third dataframe with the nearest city from city1 to city2 with the distance like :

```
           City    Country  Latitude  Longitude                     geometry    Nearest    Distance
0  Buenos Aires  Argentina    -34.58     -58.66  POINT (-58.66000 -34.58000)    Bogota    111 Km
```

Here is my actual solution using geodjango and dict (but it's way too long) :

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSGeometry
result = []
dict_result = {}
for city01 in city1 :
  dist = 99999999
  pnt = GEOSGeometry('SRID=4326;POINT( '+str(city01["Latitude"])+' '+str(city01['Longitude'])+')')
  for city02 in city2:
    pnt2 = GEOSGeometry('SRID=4326;POINT('+str(city02['Latitude'])+' '+str(city02['Longitude'])+')')
    distance_test = pnt.distance(pnt2) * 100
    if distance_test < dist :
      dist = distance_test
  result.append(dist)
  dict_result[city01['City']] = city02['City']
```

Here are my tryings :

```
from shapely.ops import nearest_points
# unary union of the gpd2 geomtries 
pts3 = gcity2df.geometry.unary_union
def Euclidean_Dist(df1, df2, cols=['x_coord','y_coord']):
    return np.linalg.norm(df1[cols].values - df2[cols].values,
                   axis=1)
def near(point, pts=pts3):
     # find the nearest point and return the corresponding Place value
     nearest = gcity2df.geometry == nearest_points(point, pts)[1]

     return gcity2df[nearest].City
gcity1df['Nearest'] = gcity1df.apply(lambda row: near(row.geometry), axis=1)
gcity1df
```

here :

```
    City    Country     Latitude    Longitude   geometry    Nearest
0   Buenos Aires    Argentina   -34.58  -58.66  POINT (-58.66000 -34.58000)     Bogota
1   Brasilia    Brazil  -15.78  -70.66  POINT (-70.66000 -15.78000)     Bogota
2   Santiago    Chile   -33.45  -70.66  POINT (-70.66000 -33.45000)     Bogota
```

Regards

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! You seem to be under the impression that StackOverflow is a site where you post a problem and get some code in return. This is in fact not the case. Your question will most likely be closed or even deleted shortly. To prevent this from happening in the future, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [take a look at the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). In particular, [make yourself famlilar as to what is regarded as on-topic around here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Also, when you post about DF please post pyhton code with the DF content, for the all the people who'd like to help you to not write on their own

Comment: @azro i've edited and added my solution to the problem and my initial data.

Comment: are your cities only in South America? If not, how far can they be from each other? How many cities can be in city1, and how many in city2? Is it important to find the fastest solution, or is a simpler solution that runs in a reasonable time OK? If the latter is the case, what would a reasonable time be?

Comment: @WalterTross my city is all around the globe , and i'am searching for the fastet solution. Thanks

Comment: @user462794 it would also be useful if we knew **how many cities can be in city1 and city2**. E.g., my solution's memory consumption scales linearly with these sizes, while a cross join would scale with their product. There are something like 10000 airports for jet planes in the world. If half of them is in city1 and the other half in city2, a cross join yields something like 25 million rows. OTOH, if numbers are low enough so that memory consumption is not a constraint, a cross join _could_ be fastest. In any case, I suggest you compare solutions using actual worst case data

Comment: @user462794, have you compared the speed using the _last_ version of the two answers?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Firstly, I merge two data frames by cross join. And then, I found distance between two points using [`map`](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#map) in python. I use `map`, because most of the time it is much faster than `apply`, `itertuples`, `iterrows` etc. (Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52674448/8205554)

Lastly, I group by data frame and fetch minimum values of distance.

Here are libraries,

```py
import pandas as pd
import geopandas
import geopy.distance
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt
```

Here are used functions,

```py
def dist1(p1, p2):
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y])

    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 

    return c * 6373

def dist2(p1, p2):
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [p1[0], p1[1], p2[0], p2[1]])

    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 

    return c * 6373

def dist3(p1, p2):
    x = p1.y, p1.x
    y = p2.y, p2.x

    return geopy.distance.geodesic(x, y).km

def dist4(p1, p2):
    x = p1[1], p1[0]
    y = p2[1], p2[0]

    return geopy.distance.geodesic(x, y).km
```

And data,

```py
city1 = [
  {
    'City': 'Buenos Aires',
    'Country': 'Argentina',
    'Latitude': -34.58,
    'Longitude': -58.66
  },
  {
    'City': 'Brasilia',
    'Country': 'Brazil',
    'Latitude': -15.78,
    'Longitude': -70.66
  },
  {
    'City': 'Santiago',
    'Country': 'Chile ',
    'Latitude': -33.45,
    'Longitude': -70.66
  }
]

city2 = [
  {
    'City': 'Bogota',
    'Country': 'Colombia ',
    'Latitude': 4.6,
    'Longitude': -74.08
  },
  {
    'City': 'Caracas',
    'Country': 'Venezuela',
    'Latitude': 10.48,
    'Longitude': -66.86
  }
]


city1df = pd.DataFrame(city1)
city2df = pd.DataFrame(city2)
```

Cross join with `geopandas` data frames,

```py
gcity1df = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(
    city1df, 
    geometry=geopandas.points_from_xy(city1df.Longitude, city1df.Latitude)
)
gcity2df = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(
    city2df, 
    geometry=geopandas.points_from_xy(city2df.Longitude, city2df.Latitude)
)

# cross join geopandas
gcity1df['key'] = 1
gcity2df['key'] = 1
merged = gcity1df.merge(gcity2df, on='key')
```

`math` functions and `geopandas`,

```py
# 6.64 ms ± 588 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%%timeit

# find distance
merged['dist'] = list(map(dist1, merged['geometry_x'], merged['geometry_y']))

mapping = {
    'City_x': 'City',
    'Country_x': 'Country',
    'Latitude_x': 'Latitude',
    'Longitude_x': 'Longitude',
    'geometry_x': 'geometry',
    'City_y': 'Nearest',
    'dist': 'Distance'
}

nearest = merged.loc[merged.groupby(['City_x', 'Country_x'])['dist'].idxmin()]
nearest.rename(columns=mapping)[list(mapping.values())]

           City    Country  Latitude  Longitude                     geometry  \
2      Brasilia     Brazil    -15.78     -70.66  POINT (-70.66000 -15.78000)   
0  Buenos Aires  Argentina    -34.58     -58.66  POINT (-58.66000 -34.58000)   
4      Santiago     Chile     -33.45     -70.66  POINT (-70.66000 -33.45000)   

  Nearest     Distance  
2  Bogota  2297.922808  
0  Bogota  4648.004515  
4  Bogota  4247.586882
```

`geopy` and `geopandas`,

```py
# 9.99 ms ± 764 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%%timeit

# find distance
merged['dist'] = list(map(dist3, merged['geometry_x'], merged['geometry_y']))

mapping = {
    'City_x': 'City',
    'Country_x': 'Country',
    'Latitude_x': 'Latitude',
    'Longitude_x': 'Longitude',
    'geometry_x': 'geometry',
    'City_y': 'Nearest',
    'dist': 'Distance'
}

nearest = merged.loc[merged.groupby(['City_x', 'Country_x'])['dist'].idxmin()]
nearest.rename(columns=mapping)[list(mapping.values())]

           City    Country  Latitude  Longitude                     geometry  \
2      Brasilia     Brazil    -15.78     -70.66  POINT (-70.66000 -15.78000)   
0  Buenos Aires  Argentina    -34.58     -58.66  POINT (-58.66000 -34.58000)   
4      Santiago     Chile     -33.45     -70.66  POINT (-70.66000 -33.45000)   

  Nearest     Distance  
2  Bogota  2285.239605  
0  Bogota  4628.641817  
4  Bogota  4226.710978
```

If you want to use `pandas` instead of `geopandas`,

```
# cross join pandas
city1df['key'] = 1
city2df['key'] = 1
merged = city1df.merge(city2df, on='key')
```

With `math` functions,

```py
# 8.65 ms ± 2.21 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%%timeit

# find distance
merged['dist'] = list(
    map(
        dist2, 
        merged[['Longitude_x', 'Latitude_x']].values, 
        merged[['Longitude_y', 'Latitude_y']].values
    )
)

mapping = {
    'City_x': 'City',
    'Country_x': 'Country',
    'Latitude_x': 'Latitude',
    'Longitude_x': 'Longitude',
    'City_y': 'Nearest',
    'dist': 'Distance'
}

nearest = merged.loc[merged.groupby(['City_x', 'Country_x'])['dist'].idxmin()]
nearest.rename(columns=mapping)[list(mapping.values())]

           City    Country  Latitude  Longitude Nearest     Distance
2      Brasilia     Brazil    -15.78     -70.66  Bogota  2297.922808
0  Buenos Aires  Argentina    -34.58     -58.66  Bogota  4648.004515
4      Santiago     Chile     -33.45     -70.66  Bogota  4247.586882
```

With `geopy`,

```py
# 9.8 ms ± 807 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%%timeit

# find distance
merged['dist'] = list(
    map(
        dist4, 
        merged[['Longitude_x', 'Latitude_x']].values, 
        merged[['Longitude_y', 'Latitude_y']].values
    )
)

mapping = {
    'City_x': 'City',
    'Country_x': 'Country',
    'Latitude_x': 'Latitude',
    'Longitude_x': 'Longitude',
    'City_y': 'Nearest',
    'dist': 'Distance'
}

nearest = merged.loc[merged.groupby(['City_x', 'Country_x'])['dist'].idxmin()]
nearest.rename(columns=mapping)[list(mapping.values())]

           City    Country  Latitude  Longitude Nearest     Distance
2      Brasilia     Brazil    -15.78     -70.66  Bogota  2285.239605
0  Buenos Aires  Argentina    -34.58     -58.66  Bogota  4628.641817
4      Santiago     Chile     -33.45     -70.66  Bogota  4226.710978
```

Comment: those distances are calculated with an approximated formula which doesn't account for the Earths flattening. Using `geopy.distance.distance()` the same 3 distances are (rounded) `2285`, `4629` and `4227` km.

Comment: I check these values with link: https://www.distance.to/-33.45,-70.66/4.6,-74.08 What's wrong?

Comment: apart from the fact that I trust more `geopy`, as a website I trust more http://edwilliams.org/gccalc.htm , which agrees with `geopy`. The website of the NOAA, https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/gccalc.shtml , says it is based on the former, but then yields different results. It is probably based on an old version of the former.

Answer (score 5):

I think it's quite difficult to find a solution with a [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) better than [O(m·n)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), where m and n are the sizes of `city1` and `city2`. Keeping the distance comparison (the only O(m·n) operation) simple, and taking advantage of the vectorized operations provided by numpy and pandas, speed should not be a problem for any reasonable input size.

The idea is that, to compare distances on a sphere, you can compare the distances between the points in 3D. The closest city is also the closest one passing *through* the sphere. Furthermore, you normally take square roots to calculate distances, but if you only need to compare them, you can avoid the square roots.

```python
from geopy.distance import distance as dist
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def find_closest(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2):
    def x_y_z_of_lat_lng_on_unit_sphere(lat, lng):
        rad_lat, rad_lng = np.radians(lat), np.radians(lng)
        sin_lat, sin_lng = np.sin(rad_lat), np.sin(rad_lng)
        cos_lat, cos_lng = np.cos(rad_lat), np.cos(rad_lng)
        return cos_lat * cos_lng, cos_lat * sin_lng, sin_lat
    x1, y1, z1 = x_y_z_of_lat_lng_on_unit_sphere(lat1, lng1)
    x2, y2, z2 = x_y_z_of_lat_lng_on_unit_sphere(lat2, lng2)
    return pd.Series(map(lambda x, y, z:
                         ((x2-x)**2 + (y2-y)**2 + (z2-z)**2).idxmin(),
                         x1, y1, z1))

city1 = [{"City":"Tokyo",    "Ctry":"JP", "Latitude": 35.68972, "Longitude": 139.69222},
         {"City":"Pretoria", "Ctry":"ZA", "Latitude":-25.71667, "Longitude": 28.28333},
         {"City":"London",   "Ctry":"GB", "Latitude": 51.50722, "Longitude": -0.12574}]
city2 = [{"City":"Seattle",  "Ctry":"US", "Latitude": 47.60972, "Longitude":-122.33306},
         {"City":"Auckland", "Ctry":"NZ", "Latitude":-36.84446, "Longitude": 174.76364}]
city1df = pd.DataFrame(city1)
city2df = pd.DataFrame(city2)

closest = find_closest(city1df.Latitude, city1df.Longitude, city2df.Latitude, city2df.Longitude)

resultdf = city1df.join(city2df, on=closest, rsuffix='2')
km = pd.Series(map(lambda latlng1, latlng2: round(dist(latlng1, latlng2).km),
                   resultdf[['Latitude',  'Longitude' ]].to_numpy(),
                   resultdf[['Latitude2', 'Longitude2']].to_numpy()))
resultdf['Distance'] = km
print(resultdf.to_string())
#        City Ctry  Latitude  Longitude     City2 Ctry2  Latitude2  Longitude2  Distance
# 0     Tokyo   JP  35.68972  139.69222   Seattle    US   47.60972  -122.33306      7715
# 1  Pretoria   ZA -25.71667   28.28333  Auckland    NZ  -36.84446   174.76364     12245
# 2    London   GB  51.50722   -0.12574   Seattle    US   47.60972  -122.33306      7723
```

Note that any solution that uses latitude and longitude as if they were Cartesian coordinates is wrong, because moving toward the poles the meridians (lines of equal longitude) get closer to each other.

Answer (score 3):

This solution probably isn't the quickest way to solve your problem, but I believe it will do the trick.

```
#New dataframe is basicly a copy of first but with more columns
gcity3df = gcity1df.copy()
gcity3df["Nearest"] = None
gcity3df["Distance"] = None

#For each city (row in gcity3df) we will calculate the nearest city from gcity2df and 
fill the Nones with results

for index, row in gcity3df.iterrows():
    #Setting neareast and distance to None, 
    #we will be filling those variables with results

    nearest = None
    distance = None
    for df2index, df2row in gcity2df.iterrows():
        d = row.geometry.distance(df2row.geometry)
        #If df2index city is closer than previous ones, replace nearest with it
        if distance is None or d < distance:
            distance = d
            nearest = df2row.City 
    #In the end we appends the closest city to gdf
    gcity3df.at[index, "Nearest"] = nearest
    gcity3df.at[index, "Distance"] = distance
```

If you need to work on meters and not degrees, you can always reproject your layer (it will also erase the mistake that Walter is meantioning). You can do it by `gcity3df = gcity3df.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:XXXX'})` where XXXX is epsg code for crs being used in your world region.