# Exploring alternatives to apply conditions to every row of dataframe other than pandas apply

Tags: python, regex, pandas, algorithm, optimization

I have a function called `postprocess` that applies while loop condition to find for `-` and `alphabets` to each dataframe row. `postprocess` looks like this:

```
def postprocess(description, start_index, end_index):
      if (start_index > 0) & (start_index < len(description)):
        while bool(re.match(r"\w|\'|-", description[start_index - 1])) & bool(
            re.match(r"\w|\'|-", description[start_index])
        ):
            start_index = start_index - 1
            if new_start == 0:
                break
      description = description[new_start:new_end]
      return description
```

For example the `description` is `credit payment velvet-burger` and the `start_index` is 7 and `end_index` is 12. So `description[start_index]` will be `b` Which is the `b` in `burger` will be run in a while loop by tracing backwards to return the target substring we want to see because `burger` is not complete as we want the word `velvet-` also.
After running `postprocess` we will get `velvet-burger`.
The complete code looks like this:

```
df["target_substring"] = df.apply(lambda x: postprocess(
                         x["description"], x["start_index"], x["end_index"]+1),
                         axis=1)
```

Is there a better way to write this code?

Comment: If your code works well and there is no issue, please consider posting the question at [codereview.se].

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to try **iterrows()** ([documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html))

```
for rowindex, rowvalues in df.iterrows():
   # do stuff with rowvalues['description']...
```

Answer (score 0):

Also take a look at `np.vectorize` from numpy module. Can really increase your code efficiency. Checkit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52673285/performance-of-pandas-apply-vs-np-vectorize-to-create-new-column-from-existing-c)