# Python Pandas: Comparison of elements in Dataframe/series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a DataFrame in a variable called "myDataFrame" that looks like this:

```
+---------+-----+-------+-----
| Type    | Count  |  Status |
+---------+-----+-------+-----
| a       |  70    |     0   |
| a       |  70    |     0   |
| b       |  70    |     0   |
| c       |  74    |     3   |
| c       |  74    |     2   |
| c       |  74    |     0   |
+---------+-----+-------+----+
```

I am using vectorized approach to process the rows in this DataFrame since the amount of rows I have is about 116 million.

So I wrote something like this:

```
myDataFrame['result'] = processDataFrame(myDataFrame['status'], myDataFrame['Count'])
```

In my function, I am trying to do this:

```
def processDataFrame(status, count):
    resultsList = list()
    if status == 0:
       resultsList.append(count + 10000)
    else:
       resultsList.append(count - 10000)

    return resultsList
```

But I get this for comparison status values:

```
Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```

What am i missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can do without self-def function

```
myDataFrame['result'] = np.where(myDataFrame['status']==0,
                                 myDataFrame['Count']+10000,
                                 myDataFrame['Count']-10000)
```

Update

```
df.apply(lambda x : processDataFrame(x['Status'],x['Count']),1)
0    [10070]
1    [10070]
2    [10070]
3    [-9926]
4    [-9926]
5    [10074]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks. While this is a good idea, I am not really worried about the result column. I do lots of other things in my function. Is there any other way to do it inside the function i mentioned?

Comment: Basically, that degrades the performance. I read lots of posts where its mentioned that using vectorized approach is the best possible solution considering the amount of data i have (116 million rows)..

I would like to do it with "vectorization" technique only, please?

Comment: @Deadman self-def function can not be vectorized , only if you can do with original  panda function

Comment: Sure, what do you mean by "original panda function". Can you give me an example please?

Comment: like panda where ， mask  and other @Deadman original ==build-in

Answer (score 0):

I think your function is not really doing the vectorized part.

When it is called, you pass `status = myDataFrame['status']`, so when it gets to the first `if`, it checks the condition of `myDataFrame['status'] == 0`.   But `myDataFrame['status'] == 0` is a boolean series (of whether each element of the `status` column equals 0), so it doesn't have a single Truth value (hence the error).  Similarly, if the condition could be met, the `resultsList` would just get the whole `"Count"` column appended, either all plus 10000 or all minus 10000.

---

**Edit:**

I suppose this function uses the built in `pandas` functions, but applies them in your function:

```
def processDataFrame(status, count):
    status_0 = (status == 0)
    output = count.copy() #if you don't want to modify in place
    output[status_0] += 10
    output[~status_0] -= 10 
    return output
```

Comment: Ok, what would be the vectorized solution?

Comment: edited to add an option; I guess per your comments with @YOBEN_S, you could change the computations to be other processing, but you would have to rely on `pandas`/`numpy` functions, and not loops/iteration

Comment: I am not too familiar with this stuff tbh, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52674448/13386979) seems informative