# how to generate column in pandas data frame using other columns and string formatting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to generate a third column in pandas dataframe using two other columns in dataframe. The requirement is very particular to the scenario for which I need to generate the third column data.

The requirement is stated as:

let the dataframe name be df, first column be 'first_name'. second column be 'last_name'.
I need to generate third column in such a manner so that it uses string formatting to generate a particular string and pass it to a function and whatever the function returns should be used as value to third column.

**Problem 1**

```
base_string = "my name is {first} {last}"

df['summary'] = base_string.format(first=df['first_name'], last=df['last_name'])
```

**Problem 2**

```
df['summary'] = some_func(base_string.format(first=df['first_name'], last=df['last_name']))
```

My ultimate goal is to solve problem 2 but for that problem 1 is pre-requisite and as of now I'm unable to solve that. I have tried converting my dataframe values to string but it is not working the way I expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `apply`:

```
df.apply(lambda r: base_string.format(first=r['first_name'], last=r['last_name']) ),
         axis=1)
```

Or list comprehension:

```
df['summary'] = [base_string.format(first=x,last=y) 
                 for x,y in zip(df['first_name'], df['last_name'])
```

And then, for general function `some_func`:

```
df['summary'] = [some_func(base_string.format(first=x,last=y) )
                 for x,y in zip(df['first_name'], df['last_name'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [pandas.DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1` so your code will look like this:

```
def mapping_function(row):
    #make your calculation
    return value
df['summary'] = df.apply(mapping_function, axis=1)
```

Comment: It works, but I think passing the entire row to a custom function would be highly inefficient.  Would be best to send only the columns necessary.

Comment: Look at this question maybe np.vectorize could work for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52673285/performance-of-pandas-apply-vs-np-vectorize-to-create-new-column-from-existing-c

Comment: Never looked into np.vectorize and my code is plagued with slow.apply(custom_funcs). Really great tip, will definitely checkout :)

Comment: Yeah, I found it out just now. It's useful for some of my python notebook too. Cheers.

Comment: Note that `np.vectorize` is **not** vecterization by any mean. It is just a wrapped `for` loop.