# Is there a better way than using np.vectorize to use function on ndarray of ndarray of different shape?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

The following function apply numpy functions to two numpy arrays.

```
import numpy as np

def my_func(a: np.ndarray, b: np.ndarray) -> float:
    return np.nanmin(a, axis=0) + np.nanmin(b, axis=0)

>>> my_func(np.array([1., 2., np.nan]), np.array([1., np.nan]))
2.0
```

However what is the best way to apply this same function to an np.array of np.array of different shape  ?

```
a = np.array([np.array([1., 2]), np.array([1, 2., 3, np.nan])], dtype=object)  # First array shape (2,), second (3,)
b = np.array([np.array([1]), np.array([1.5, 2.5, np.nan])], dtype=object)
```

np.vectorize does work

```
>>> np.vectorize(my_func)(a, b)
array([2. , 2.5])
```

but as specified by [the vectorize documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html):

> The vectorize function is provided primarily for convenience, not for
> performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop.

Is there a more clever solution ?
I could use [np.pad](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) to have identifical shape but it seems sub-optimal as it requires to pad up to the maximum length of the inside arrays (here 4 for `a` and 3 for `b`).

I looked at [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/vectorize.html) and [this stack exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52673285/performance-of-pandas-apply-vs-np-vectorize-to-create-new-column-from-existing-c) about performance but I am not sure of the best pratice for such a case.

Thanks !

Comment: Not only is `np.vectorize` not a speed tool, it passes the arrays element by element to function.  It's useful for a function that only works with scalar inputs, and you are too lazy to rewrite to work with arrays (or some cases can't).

Comment: OK, I see you are passing object dtype arrays, so `vectorize` will pass those array elements.  The fast numpy methods ("real" vectorization) work with numeric dtype arrays.  Object dtype arrays are processed at least speads.  There isn't a "fast" way of using those object arrays.

Comment: Indeed here I have different shapes so I can't just rewrite the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function and arrays:

```
In [222]: def my_func(a: np.ndarray, b: np.ndarray) -> float:
     ...:     return np.nanmin(a, axis=0) + np.nanmin(b, axis=0)
     ...: 
In [223]: a = np.array([np.array([1., 2]), np.array([1, 2., 3, np.nan])], dtype=object
     ...: )  # First array shape (2,), second (3,)
     ...: b = np.array([np.array([1]), np.array([1.5, 2.5, np.nan])], dtype=object)
In [224]: a
Out[224]: array([array([1., 2.]), array([ 1.,  2.,  3., nan])], dtype=object)
In [225]: b
Out[225]: array([array([1]), array([1.5, 2.5, nan])], dtype=object)
```

Compare `vectorize` with a straightforward list comprehension:

```
In [226]: np.vectorize(my_func)(a, b)
Out[226]: array([2. , 2.5])
In [227]: [my_func(i,j) for i,j in zip(a,b)]
Out[227]: [2.0, 2.5]
```

and their times:

```
In [228]: timeit np.vectorize(my_func)(a, b)
157 µs ± 117 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [229]: timeit [my_func(i,j) for i,j in zip(a,b)]
85.9 µs ± 148 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [230]: timeit np.array([my_func(i,j) for i,j in zip(a,b)])
89.7 µs ± 1.03 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

If you are going to work with object arrays, `frompyfunc` is faster than `vectorize`:

```
In [231]: np.frompyfunc(my_func,2,1)(a, b)
Out[231]: array([2.0, 2.5], dtype=object)
In [232]: timeit np.frompyfunc(my_func,2,1)(a, b)
83.2 µs ± 50.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

I'm a bit surprised that it's even better than the list comprehension.

`frompyfunc` (and `vectorize`) are more useful when the inputs need to 'broadcast' against each other:

```
In [233]: np.frompyfunc(my_func,2,1)(a[:,None], b)
Out[233]: 
array([[2.0, 2.5],
       [2.0, 2.5]], dtype=object)
```

I'm not a `numba` expert, but I suspect it doesn't handle object dtype arrays, or it it does it doesn't improve speed much.  Remember, object dtype  means the elements are object references, just like in lists.

I get better times by using `otypes` and taking the function creation out of the timing loop:

```
In [235]: %%timeit f=np.vectorize(my_func, otypes=[float])
     ...: f(a, b)
     ...: 
     ...: 
95.5 µs ± 316 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [236]: %%timeit f=np.frompyfunc(my_func,2,1)
     ...: f(a, b)
     ...: 
     ...: 
81.1 µs ± 103 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

If you don't know about `otypes`, you haven't read the `np.vectorize` docs well enough.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj for your answer. I though I was maybe missing a  subtlety of numpy but apparently not.