# Issue with multiple conditionals within a lambda function being applied to multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I am attempting to populate a column titled 'label' which is the result of conditional statements within  a lambda function which involves two columns of the data frame. I would like to create numerical labels based off of specific conditions found within the 'WY' and 'WY Week' columns. For example the label is 1 if WY is less than 2010 and 2 if WY is greater than 2010 and 3 if the WY value is greater than 2010 for WY Week values between 26 and 40.

I dont have an issue with one conditional for one column as seen below:

```
GC['label'] = GC['WY'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x >= 1985 else 0)
```

But I throw a code when I attempt to write a conditional statement involving two columns and multiple conditions:

```
CJ['label'] = CJ[['WY','WY Week']].apply(lambda x,y: 1 if x < 2010 else (2 if x >= 2010 and (y >= 26 and y <= 40)) else )
```

The error is a syntax error:

```
File "<ipython-input-21-6b6fa416588d>", line 7
CJ['label'] = CJ[['WY','WY Week'].apply(lambda x,y: 1 if x < 2010 else (2 if x >= 2010) and (y >= 26 and y <= 40) else )
                                                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I feel like i'm pretty close but would like some assistance as it is 1 of several conditional statements that I need to write like this.

Comment: You have nothing after the last `else`. What should the value be in that case?

Comment: `CJ[['WY','WY Week']` You're missing a closing `]`. `CJ[['WY','WY Week']]`.  Ternary operator without an else is not permitted in python  `(2 if x >= 2010)` Can you outline what you are trying to accomplish? Because it is not immediately clear from the provided code.

Comment: Also, the last `else` needs to be inside the `(2 if x >= 2010 ...)` parentheses.

Comment: I suggest you don't do this with `lambda`, you're just making it confusing by trying to put everything into one line. Define a named function and use `if` statements.

Comment: @HenryEcker I fixed the bracket. Big oversight on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a named function instead of trying to cram everything into a complex `lambda`.

There's no need to test `x >= 2010` in the `else`; if it gets to the `else`, that must be true.

```
def labelval(x, y):
    if x < 2010:
        return 1
    elif 26 <= y <= 40:
        return 2
    else:
        return 3

CJ['label'] = CJ[['WY','WY Week']].apply(labelval)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
# hopefully a readable function that makes label conditions clear
def classify(wy, wy_week):
    if wy < 2020:
        return 1
    elif 26 <= wy_week <= 40
        return 2
    else:
        return 3 # I guess?

# fast, vectorized calculation using two columns
GB['label'] = list(map(classify,GC['WY'],GC['WY Week']))
```

One of my favorite best stack overflow answers ever:
[Performance of Pandas apply vs np.vectorize to create new column from existing columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52673285/performance-of-pandas-apply-vs-np-vectorize-to-create-new-column-from-existing-c)

Comment: I didn't see @Barmar's when I submitted mine!  His is good too!

Comment: That was a great link. Relatively new to python and programming as a whole so trying out new things as a trial by fire even though they may not be the most efficient. The link was helpful and I think I will combine both @Barmar solution as well as yours to complete what I am trying to do.