# Is there a fast (vectorized) way to count a list of string contained within another list of strings?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to count the number of two character vowel permutations that are contained within a list of 5-letter words.  Vowel permutations are like `'aa','ae','ai,...,'ui','uo','uu'`.

I successfully get this done using `apply()` but it is slow.  I want to see if there is a fast vectorized way to get this done.  I can't think of one.

Here's what I did:

```
import pandas as pd 
import itertools

vowels = list('aeiou')
vowel_perm = [x[0]+x[1] for x in itertools.product(vowels,vowels)]  

def wide_contains(x):
    return pd.Series(data=[c in x for c in vowel_perm], index=vowel_perm) 

dfwd['word'].apply(wide_contains).sum()

aa     1
ae     2
ai    12
ao     2
au     8
ea    15
ee    15
ei     1
eo     5
eu     2
ia     7
ie    10
ii     0
io     3
iu     0
oa     2
oe     2
oi     3
oo    11
ou     7
ua     2
ue     9
ui     2
uo     0
uu     0
```

**The above is the expected output using the following data**

```
word_lst = ['gaize', 'musie', 'dauts', 'orgue', 'tough', 'medio', 'roars', 'leath', 'quire', 'kaons', 'iatry', 'tuath', 'tarea', 'hairs', 'sloid', 
'beode', 'fours', 'belie', 'qaids', 'cobia', 'cokie', 'wreat', 'spoom', 'soaps', 'usque', 'frees', 'rials', 'youve', 'dreed', 'feute', 
'saugh', 'esque', 'revue', 'noels', 'seism', 'sneer', 'geode', 'vicua', 'maids', 'fiord', 'bread', 'squet', 'goers', 'sneap', 'teuch', 
'arcae', 'roosa', 'spues', 'could', 'tweeg', 'coiny', 'cread', 'airns', 'gauds', 'aview', 'mudee', 'vario', 'spaid', 'pooka', 'bauge', 
'beano', 'snies', 'boose', 'holia', 'doums', 'goopy', 'feaze', 'kneel', 'gains', 'acoin', 'crood', 'juise', 'gluey', 'zowie', 'biali', 
'leads', 'twaes', 'fogie', 'wreak', 'keech', 'bairn', 'spies', 'ghoom', 'foody', 'jails', 'waird', 'iambs', 'woold', 'belue', 'bisie', 
'hauls', 'deans', 'eaten', 'aurar', 'anour', 'utees', 'sayee', 'droob', 'gagee', 'roleo', 'burao', 'tains', 'daubs', 'geeky', 'civie', 
'scoop', 'sidia', 'tuque', 'fairy', 'taata', 'eater', 'beele', 'obeah', 'feeds', 'feods', 'absee', 'meous', 'cream', 'beefy', 'nauch']

dfwd = pd.DataFrame(word_lst, columns=['word'])
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52674448/6627366) might help

Comment: is your original data a list or a DataFrame column?

Comment: @enke Original data is a DF column

Comment: Use python for the computation ... Pandas does not have any vectorized string operations, as it uses python string methods under the hood

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if not using Pandas to do this computation at all is alright, it looks like plain old `Counter()` is 220x faster on my machine for the data given.

```
from collections import Counter
import timeit


def timetest(func, name=None):
    name = name or getattr(func, "__name__", None)
    iters, time = timeit.Timer(func).autorange()
    iters_per_sec = iters / time
    print(f"{name=} {iters=} {time=:.3f} {iters_per_sec=:.2f}")


def counter():
    ctr = Counter()
    for word in dfwd['word']:
        for perm in vowel_perm:
            if perm in word:
                ctr[perm] += 1
    return ctr


timetest(original)
timetest(counter)
print(counter())
```

outputs

```
name='original' iters=10 time=0.229 iters_per_sec=43.59
name='counter' iters=2000 time=0.212 iters_per_sec=9434.29
Counter({'ea': 15, 'ee': 15, 'ai': 12, 'oo': 11, 'ie': 10, 'ue': 9, 'au': 8, 'ou': 7, 'ia': 7, 'eo': 5, 'io': 3, 'oi': 3, 'oa': 2, 'ui': 2, 'ao': 2, 'ua': 2, 'eu': 2, 'oe': 2, 'ae': 2, 'ei': 1, 'aa': 1})
```

Comment: Thanks.  Great answer.  Couldn't find `from itertools import Counter` but `from collections import Counter` did work.

Comment: Oop, yeah, typo :)

Comment: It is kind of refreshing to see a good-old nested loop come in as the fastest solution (by my testing on my machine).

Answer (score 3):

How about some dictionary comprehension? It should be faster than using `apply`

```
{v: dfwd['word'].str.count(v).sum() for v in vowel_perm}
# 6.9 ms ± 180 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

{'aa': 1,
 'ae': 2,
 'ai': 12,
 'ao': 2,
 'au': 8,
 'ea': 15,
 'ee': 15,
 'ei': 1,
 'eo': 5,
 'eu': 2,
 'ia': 7,
 'ie': 10,
 'ii': 0,
 'io': 3,
 'iu': 0,
 'oa': 2,
 'oe': 2,
 'oi': 3,
 'oo': 11,
 'ou': 7,
 'ua': 2,
 'ue': 9,
 'ui': 2,
 'uo': 0,
 'uu': 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to simply iterate over the the vowel pairs and count the number of occurrences in `word_lst` of each pair. Note that for the current task, you don't need to create an explicit list: `vowel_perm` either, simply iterate over the map object:

```
out = pd.Series({pair: sum(True for w in word_lst if pair in w) 
                 for pair in map(''.join, itertools.product(vowels,vowels))})
```

On my machine, a benchmark says:

```
>>> %timeit out = pd.Series({pair: sum(True for w in word_lst if pair in w) for pair in map(''.join, itertools.product(vowels,vowels))})
492 µs ± 28.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
>>> %timeit vowel_perm = [x[0]+x[1] for x in itertools.product(vowels,vowels)]; out = dfwd['word'].apply(wide_contains).sum()
40.6 ms ± 2.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: This seems to be about as half as fast as my Counter-based answer for the given dataset (on my machine).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy.char.find` to search an array of string for a substring:

```py
from itertools import product

word_lst = np.array([
    'gaize', 'musie', 'dauts', 'orgue', 'tough', 'medio', 'roars', 'leath', 'quire', 'kaons', 'iatry', 'tuath', 'tarea', 'hairs', 'sloid', 
    'beode', 'fours', 'belie', 'qaids', 'cobia', 'cokie', 'wreat', 'spoom', 'soaps', 'usque', 'frees', 'rials', 'youve', 'dreed', 'feute', 
    'saugh', 'esque', 'revue', 'noels', 'seism', 'sneer', 'geode', 'vicua', 'maids', 'fiord', 'bread', 'squet', 'goers', 'sneap', 'teuch', 
    'arcae', 'roosa', 'spues', 'could', 'tweeg', 'coiny', 'cread', 'airns', 'gauds', 'aview', 'mudee', 'vario', 'spaid', 'pooka', 'bauge', 
    'beano', 'snies', 'boose', 'holia', 'doums', 'goopy', 'feaze', 'kneel', 'gains', 'acoin', 'crood', 'juise', 'gluey', 'zowie', 'biali', 
    'leads', 'twaes', 'fogie', 'wreak', 'keech', 'bairn', 'spies', 'ghoom', 'foody', 'jails', 'waird', 'iambs', 'woold', 'belue', 'bisie', 
    'hauls', 'deans', 'eaten', 'aurar', 'anour', 'utees', 'sayee', 'droob', 'gagee', 'roleo', 'burao', 'tains', 'daubs', 'geeky', 'civie', 
    'scoop', 'sidia', 'tuque', 'fairy', 'taata', 'eater', 'beele', 'obeah', 'feeds', 'feods', 'absee', 'meous', 'cream', 'beefy', 'nauch'
], dtype="U")

dfwd = pd.Series({
    perm: (np.char.find(word_lst, perm) != -1).sum()
    for perm in ["".join(p) for p in product(list("aoeui"), repeat=2)]
})
```

Comment: This doesn't get the counts, though, as OP wants..?

Comment: @AKX thanks for the reminder. My bad for not reading through the question!

Comment: Thanks.  Great answer.  FYI ... `itertools.permutations` doesn't produce repeated elements like `'aa','oo','ee'`

Comment: @jch yes you are right. I should’ve taken a break from coding today. Not a productive day for me. 

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

```
df['word'].str.extractall('([aeiou]{2})').groupby([0]).size()
```

Output:

```
0
aa     1
ae     2
ai    12
ao     2
au     8
ea    15
ee    15
ei     1
eo     5
eu     2
ia     7
ie    10
io     3
oa     2
oe     2
oi     3
oo    11
ou     6
ua     2
ue     9
ui     2
```

Comment: Wow.  Great idea - and fast.  Another variation on that:  `df['word'].str.extractall('([aeiou]{2})').value_counts()`