# Using pd.apply with a series argument gives TypeError

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to calculate the distance between two pairs of lat/long with a haversine formula.  I am using a series for the last two function arguments because I am trying to calculate this for multiple coordinates that I have stored in two pandas columns.  I'm getting the following error `TypeError: ("'Series' object is not callable", u'occurred at index 0')`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt

origin_lat = 51.507200
origin_lon = -0.127500

def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points 
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)
    """
    # convert decimal degrees to radians 
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(np.radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])

    # haversine formula 
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a)) 
    r = 6371 # Radius of earth in kilometers. Use 3956 for miles
    return c * r

df['dist_from_org'] = df.apply(haversine(origin_lon, origin_lat, df['ulong'], df['ulat']), axis=1)
```

The series from the df look like this:

```
+----+---------+----------+
|    |  ulat   |  ulong   |
+----+---------+----------+
|  0 | 52.6333 | 1.30000  |
|  1 | 51.4667 | -0.35000 |
|  2 | 51.5084 | -0.12550 |
|  3 | 51.8833 | 0.56670  |
|  4 | 51.7667 | -1.38330 |
|  5 | 55.8667 | -2.10000 |
|  6 | 55.8667 | -2.10000 |
|  7 | 52.4667 | -1.91670 |
|  8 | 51.8833 | 0.90000  |
|  9 | 53.4083 | -2.14940 |
| 10 | 53.0167 | -1.73330 |
| 11 | 51.4667 | -0.35000 |
| 12 | 51.4667 | -0.35000 |
| 13 | 52.7167 | -1.36670 |
| 14 | 51.4667 | -0.35000 |
| 15 | 52.9667 | -1.16667 |
| 16 | 51.4667 | -0.35000 |
| 17 | 51.8833 | 0.56670  |
| 18 | 51.8833 | 0.56670  |
| 19 | 51.4833 | 0.08330  |
| 20 | 52.0833 | 0.58330  |
| 21 | 52.3000 | -0.70000 |
| 22 | 51.4000 | -0.05000 |
| 23 | 51.9333 | -2.10000 |
| 24 | 51.9000 | -0.43330 |
| 25 | 53.4809 | -2.23740 |
| 26 | 51.4853 | -3.18670 |
| 27 | 51.2000 | -1.48333 |
| 28 | 51.7779 | -3.21170 |
| 29 | 51.4667 | -0.35000 |
| 30 | 51.7167 | -0.28330 |
| 31 | 52.2000 | 0.11670  |
| 32 | 52.4167 | -1.55000 |
| 33 | 56.5000 | -2.96670 |
| 34 | 51.2167 | -1.05000 |
| 35 | 51.8964 | -2.07830 |
+----+---------+----------+
```

Am I not allowed to use a series in a pd.apply function? If so how can I apply a function row by row and assign the output to a new column?

Comment: check your code `df.apply(...`, shouldn't it be `pd.apply(...` ? P.S. I know nothing about pandas

Comment: @Pynchia Nope, I'm almost positive, it needs to be `df`, the code is not shown, but my dataframe is called `df`

Comment: What are origin_lon, origin_lat?  Are the constant or do they change for each row in the table?  BTW, it's a DataFrame, not a series (there are multiple columns).

Comment: @Alexander sorry, let me update the code, yes they are constant. wouldn't calling df['ulong'] be a series though?

Comment: Could you see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25767596/using-haversine-formula-with-data-stored-in-a-pandas-dataframe/25767765#25767765

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use apply when calling the function.  Just use:

```
df['dist_from_org'] = haversine(origin_lon, origin_lat, df['ulong'], df['ulat'])
```

When I ran your code (using scalar values for origin_lon, origin_lat, I got TypeError: cannot convert the series to .  This was caused by the assignment `a = ...`

I reworked the formulae to apply to series:

```
a = dlat.divide(2).apply(sin).pow(2) 
    + lat1.apply(cos).multiply(lat2.apply(cos).multiply(dlon.divide(2).apply(sin).pow(2)))
```

Let me know if this works for you.

if origin_lon and origin_lat are constants (as opposed to a series), then use this formula:

```
a = dlat.divide(2).apply(sin).pow(2) + cos(lat1) * lat2.apply(cos).multiply(dlon.divide(2).apply(sin).pow(2))
```

Because the parameters lon2 and lat2 are Pandas Series, dlon and dlat will both be Series objects as well.  You then need to use [apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) on the series to apply the function to each element in the list.

Comment: Still getting the error  `TypeError: ("'Series' object is not callable", u'occurred at index 0')`

Comment: try >>> haversine(origin_lon, origin_lat, df['ulong'], df['ulat']) What does that return?

Comment: Okay, I just restarted the kernel in my ipython notebook and now with the above i get this error - `AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'apply'` for the a= code that you gave above

Comment: I added a formula for a if the origin_lon and origin_lat are constants.

Comment: It works! could you please explain why you needed to change the `a=` formula from what I had originally?