# Python: simplifying code by writing it in a more Pandas specific way

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote some code that finds the distance between gps coordinates based on machines having the same serial numbers looking at

- [Fast Haversine Approximation (Python/Pandas)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29545704/fast-but-not-very-accurate-method-for-finding-distance-between-2-points-using)

But I believe it will be more efficient if it can be simplified to using `iterrows` or `df.apply`; however, I cannot seems to figure it out.

Since I need to only execute the function when `ser_no[i] == ser_no[i+1]` and insert a `NaN` value at the location where the ser_no changes, I cannot seem to apply the Pandas methodology to make the code more efficient. I have looked at:

- [Vectorised Haversine formula with a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25767596/using-haversine-formula-with-data-stored-in-a-pandas-dataframe)
- [Python function to calculate distance using haversine formula in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34510749/python-function-to-calculate-distance-using-haversine-formula-in-pandas)
- [Vectorizing a function in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27575854/vectorizing-a-function-in-pandas)

Unfortunately, I don't readily see the leap I need to make even after looking over these posts.

> What I have:

```
def haversine(lat1, long1, lat2, long2):
    r = 6371  # radius of Earth in km
    # convert decimals to degrees
    lat1, long1, lat2, long2 = map(np.radians, [lat1, long1, lat2, long2])
    # haversine formula
    lat = lat2 - lat1
    lon = long2 - long1
    a = np.sin(lat/2)**2 + np.cos(lat1)*np.cos(lat2)*np.sin(lon/2)**2
    c = 2*np.arcsin(np.sqrt(a))
    d = r*c
    return d
# pre-allocate vector    
hdist = np.zeros(len(mttt_pings.index), dtype = float)    
# haversine loop calculation
for i in range(0, len(mttt_pings.index) - 1):
    '''
    when the ser_no from i and i + 1 are the same calculate the distance
    between them using the haversine formula and put the distance in the
    i + 1 location
    '''
    if mttt_pings.ser_no.loc[i] == mttt_pings.ser_no[i + 1]:
        hdist[i + 1] = haversine(mttt_pings.EQP_GPS_SPEC_LAT_CORD[i], \
        mttt_pings.EQP_GPS_SPEC_LONG_CORD[i], \
        mttt_pings.EQP_GPS_SPEC_LAT_CORD[i + 1], \
        mttt_pings.EQP_GPS_SPEC_LONG_CORD[i + 1])
    else:
        hdist = np.insert(hdist, i, np.nan)
    '''
    when ser_no i and i + 1 are not the same, insert NaN at the ith location
    '''
```

Comment: Could you post a sample of your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea is to utilize `shift` to check consecutive rows.  I'm also writing a `get_dist` function just wraps your existing distance function to make things more readable for when I use `apply` to compute distances.

```
def get_dist(row):
    lat1 = row['EQP_GPS_SPEC_LAT_CORD']
    long1 = row['EQP_GPS_SPEC_LONG_CORD']
    lat2 = row['EQP_GPS_SPEC_LAT_CORD_2']
    long2 = row['EQP_GPS_SPEC_LONG_CORD_2']
    return haversine(lat1, long1, lat2, long2)

# Find consecutive rows with matching ser_no, and get coordinates.
coord_cols = ['EQP_GPS_SPEC_LAT_CORD', 'EQP_GPS_SPEC_LONG_CORD']
matching_ser = mttt_pings['ser_no'] == mttt_pings['ser_no'].shift(1)
shift_coords = mttt_pings.shift(1).loc[matching_ser, coord_cols]

# Join shifted coordinates and compute distances.
mttt_pings_shift = mttt_pings.join(shift_coords, how='inner', rsuffix='_2')
mttt_pings['hdist'] = mttt_pings_shift.apply(get_dist, axis=1)
```

In the above code, I've added the distances to your dataframe.  If you want to get the result as a numpy array, you can do:

```
hdist = mttt_pings['hdist'].values
```

As a side note, you may want to consider using [`geopy.distance.vincenty`](http://geopy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#geopy.distance.vincenty) to compute distances between lat/long coordinates.  In general, `vincenty` is more accurate than `haversine`, although it may take longer to compute.  Very minor modifications to the `get_dist` function are required to use `vincenty`.

```
from geopy.distance import vincenty

def get_dist(row):
    lat1 = row['EQP_GPS_SPEC_LAT_CORD']
    long1 = row['EQP_GPS_SPEC_LONG_CORD']
    lat2 = row['EQP_GPS_SPEC_LAT_CORD_2']
    long2 = row['EQP_GPS_SPEC_LONG_CORD_2']
    return vincenty((lat1, long1), (lat2, long2)).km
```