# Pandas: apply a specific function to columns and create other columns

Tags: python, loops, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe `df` with geographical coordinates like this:

```
    lat         lon         
0   48.01025772 -6.15690851 
1   48.02164841 -6.10588741 
2   48.03302765 -6.05480051 
... ...         ...
```

I need to convert these coordinates into a different system, and have a dedicated function for this. I plan to create two new columns, `df['N']` which is paired with `lat`, and `df['E']` which is paired with `lon`.

It's not relevant what the function looks like, so for simplicity let's call it *f*. The function operates like this: `E, N = f(float(lat), float(lon))`

Is there a way I can iterate through all rows of `df`, extract the `lat,lon` pair, (compute their transformation) and assign the values to the relevant columns?

Comment: if you're interested I wrote a method for calculating haversine in a vectorised manner, this will give you some idea of how you maybe able to rewrite whatever your function does: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25767596/using-haversine-formula-with-data-stored-in-a-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply) on the df and pass `axis=1`, in your function you should return a `Series` and assign the 2 columns directly:

```
In [207]:
def foo(lat, lon):
    return pd.Series([lat + 10, lon * 100])
​
df[['new_lat','new_lon']] = df.apply(lambda x: foo(x['lat'], x['lon']), axis=1)
df

Out[207]:
         lat       lon    new_lat   new_lon
0  48.010258 -6.156909  58.010258 -615.6909
1  48.021648 -6.105887  58.021648 -610.5887
2  48.033028 -6.054801  58.033028 -605.4801
```

depending on what your function is doing using `apply` can and should be avoided

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid creating pd.Series as it takes a lot of time and pass `result_type='expand'` argument instead. This runs noticeably faster on big Dataframes

```
def foo(lat, lon):
    return [lat + 10, lon * 100]

df[['new_lat','new_lon']] = df.apply(lambda x: foo(x['lat'], x['lon']), axis=1, result_type='expand')
```

On my Dataframe the following timing was achieved: Pure apply(no assigning, returns list) - 27 sec, with `result_type='expand'` - 30 sec, with return pd.Series(...) - 41 sec.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
df[['lat', 'lon']].apply(lambda row: f(float(row['lat']), float(row['lon']), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't always know the number, name or order of columns returned, this solution is more flexible:

```py
    exploded = df.apply(lambda x: ..., axis='columns', result_type='expand')

    return pd.concat([df, exploded], axis='columns', sort=False)
```