# Creating a multidimensional numpy array of tuples from multiple pandas series and processing it

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to calculate the haversine distance between two points and make a new pandas series from the result of the computation. My input comes from four different pandas series, namely: pickup_longitude, pickup_latitude, dropoff_longitude, dropoff_latitude.

A function from the haversine module that calculates the distance has the following signature:

```
p1 = (x1, y1)
p2 = (x2, y2)
haversine(p1, p2): return distance between p1 and p2
```

I'm curious if there is a fast, pythonic way to do this.

Here's my naive solution:

```
pulo = train['pickup_longitude'].values
pula = train['pickup_latitude'].values
dolo = train['dropoff_longitude'].values
dola = train['dropoff_latitude'].values

pickup_list = list(zip(pulo,pula))
dropoff_list = list(zip(dolo, dola))

coords = []

for i in range(len(train)):
    coords.append([pickup_list[i], dropoff_list[i]])

haversines = []
for i in range(len(coords)):
    haversines.append(haversine(coords[i][0], coords[i][1]))

train['distance'] = np.asarray(haversines)
```

Comment: Could you indulge us and provide some sample data, so we could copy-n-paste your code and run it?  It would save us effort when constructing answers - and ensure that the answers are really useful.

Comment: If you're working on vehicle routing, this structure is not useful. You want a 2D matrix of location IDs and, if necessary, a mapping of location ID to the lat/long in a separate dict.

Comment: The data comes from a kaggle competition, namely https://www.kaggle.com/c/nyc-taxi-trip-duration.
I want to compute the distance, because I'm guessing that it might be an important feature for the model.
First (relevant data only) row of the data set: 
pickup_datetime       2016-03-14 17:24:55
dropoff_datetime      2016-03-14 17:32:30
passenger_count                         1
pickup_longitude                 -73.9822
pickup_latitude                   40.7679
dropoff_longitude                -73.9646
dropoff_latitude                  40.7656
trip_duration                         455

Comment: Huh, what a strange competition. This should be done in-house and can make use lot of of 3rd party libraries that can do these things accurately by road distance and speed limit e.g. Jsprit (contributor) and OSRM before layering this logic on top. Working on several systems for national delivery companies, looks like they're throwing money away, a decent system takes at least a year, but I guess that's not your issue :P

Comment: This question is specifically about haversine implenetation in pandas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25767596/vectorised-haversine-formula-with-a-pandas-dataframe