# How to use haversine distance using haversine library on pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, haversine

Here's using how I use haversine library to calculate distance between two points

```
import haversine as hs
hs.haversine((106.11333888888888,-1.94091666666667),(96.698661, 5.204783))
```

Here's how to calculate haversine distance using sklearn

```
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import haversine_distances
import numpy as np
radian_1 = np.radians(df1[['lat','lon']])
radian_2 = np.radians(df2[['lat','lon']])
D = pd.DataFrame(haversine_distances(radian_1,radian_2)*6371,index=df1.index, columns=df2.index)
```

What i need is doing similar things but instead using `sklearn.metrics.pairwise` library, I use `haversine` library

Here's my dataset `df1`

```
   index       lon        lat
0   0   107.071969  -6.347778
1   1   110.431361  -7.773489
2   2   111.978469  -8.065442
```

and dataset `df2`

```
    index      lon        lat
5   5   112.340919  -7.520442
6   6   107.179119  -6.291131
7   7   106.807442  -6.437383
```

Here's expected output

```
        5           6           7
    0  596.019968   13.413123   30.882602
    1  212.317223  394.942014  426.564799
    2   72.573637  565.020998  598.409848
```

Comment: can you check is [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25767596/vectorised-haversine-formula-with-a-pandas-dataframe) is what you need?

Comment: Not, what I need is cross-tab distance, I will give my expoected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product` for creating all cases then use `haversine` for getting results like the below:

```
import haversine as hs
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools

res = []
for a,b in (itertools.product(*[df1.values , df2.values])):
    res.append(hs.haversine(a,b))

m = int(np.sqrt(len(res)))
df = pd.DataFrame(np.asarray(res).reshape(m,m))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
            0           1           2
0  587.500555   12.058061   29.557005
1  212.580742  365.487782  405.718803
2   46.333180  537.684789  578.072579
```

Answer (score 1):

Following the documentation and example found on: [sklearn.metrics.haversine](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.haversine_distances.html)

```
result = haversine_distances(np.radians(df_1[["lat","lon"]]), np.radians(df_2[["lat", "lon"]])) * 6371000/1000
result_df = pd.DataFrame(result, index = df_1["index"], columns=df_2["index"])
```

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th>index</th>
      <th>5</th>
      <th>6</th>
      <th>7</th> </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>index</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th> </tr> </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>596.019968</td>
      <td>13.413123</td>
      <td>30.882602</td> </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>212.317223</td>
      <td>394.942014</td>
      <td>426.564799</td> </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2</th>
      <td>72.573637</td>
      <td>565.020998</td>
      <td>598.409848</td> </tr> </tbody> </table>
```

You first need to convert the latitude and longitude to radians, and once you get back the distance you need to multiply by the earth radius to get the correct distance.

Comment: I'm asking using `haversine` library, not using `sklearn`